# What is the limit of the following expression?

Tags: limits, central-limit-theorem, indeterminate-forms

I've been thinking about and trying to solve the following limit that I just feel lost by now. I always get an indeterminate form. I don't know what else to try. In the picture is just one way that I tried to do it, again resulting in an indeterminate:
[image]

Can you help?

$lim_{n\to \infty} \left[ \left(3+\dfrac{1}{n} \right)^{-3n} * 27^n\right]$

Comment: Central limit theorem? Where?

Comment: Do you know anything about $\left(a+\frac1n\right)^n?$

Comment: Bogdan, this looks like a good question. Would you mind putting it in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? I would if I could, but am currently away from my computer.

Comment: @Federico Yes, but I don't see how to apply it here.

Comment: @JackMoody I'm sorry but I am unfamiliar with MathJax. I don't even have it.

Comment: @Federico Actually no, I'm not familiar with that formula. I misread it. I thought that in order for that to equal $e$ the $a$ has to be $1$. But I didn't know it could have an $a$ instead of $1$. What is it equal to?

Comment: @BogdanVlad MathJax is just a certain notation you can use to make math render nicely on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JackMoody Oh, my bad. I didn't know. I put it at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\dfrac{t}{3}$ then your limit will be
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)^{-t}=\dfrac{1}{e}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please explain it a bit further? Where and what should I replace with $t$ ?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it (with your idea). Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should replace $x=\dfrac{t}{3}$ at the first limit $$(3+\dfrac{1}{\frac{t}{3}})^{-3\frac{t}{3}}=(3+\dfrac{3}{t})^{-t}=3^{-t}(1+\dfrac{1}{t})^{-t}$$also $$27^x=(3^3)^\dfrac{t}{3}=3^t$$

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion was to notice that
$$
\left(a+\frac1n\right)^n = \left(a+\frac{a}{an}\right)^n
= a^n\left(1+\frac1{an}\right)^n \sim a^ne^{1/a}.
$$

You can compute your limit as
$$
\left(3+\frac1n\right)^{-3n}3^{3n}
= 3^{-3n}\left(1+\frac1{3n}\right)^{-3n}3^{3n}=\left(1+\frac1{3n}\right)^{-3n}
\to e^{-1}.
$$